# Error during installation of Mesa on Linux

Tags: linux, graphics, centos, opengl

I try to install Mesa 7.8 on CentOS 3.9 for i386 on VMVare 7.0.1 like described here:
http://linux-sxs.org/multimedia/mesa.html

When I perform configuration stage:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[root@CentOS Mesa-7.8]# ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
(root is actualy root)
This is what I get:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
.
.
.
checking pkg-config files for X11 are available... no
checking for X... no
configure: error: X11 development libraries needed for dri driver
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
(Three dots says that there is some output before)
Put attention to error.

Any idea?
Thank you very much forahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the X11 dev libraries.

Depending on your package system (rpm on CentOs probably), they could be called

```
libx11-devel
xorg-x11-devel
...
```

or something along these lines. Install that and you should be fine (for this particular error).

Comment: Thank you very much,  
I do:  
yum install libx11-devel  
and I get:  
--  
Cannot find a package matching libx11-devel  
No actions to take  
--  
It says that I need other yum repository? (I new in Linux)  
And second question, what is a different between development library   and non-development library, because they both .so? Arn't they?  "development" may be only code text file or library with debug  information...

Comment: @rodnower: The difference is that the .so files in the non-development libraries will all have version numbers after them so that two programs that are linked against different versions of the same library can pick up the correct one. The single .so file that comes with the development package will have no version number as this is what the linker will look for during the build process. The development package will also come with the headers that are needed to compile the code that will ultimately link to the library.

Comment: Aha, now I understand what is a difference. Thank you very much.
But some one know what the name of X11 development packages for CentOS 3? Or it is the same of other destributives like Fedora?

Comment: @rod: `yum search x11-devel` tells me that it is called `libX11-devel` in Fedora. Use search on your system and install only via `yum` to get the right package for your installation.

Comment: Good, now I will reinstall my CentOS (from v 3 to 5) and than I will try. Thank you :)